# Does std::bind have boost-like overloaded operators for its result?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, stdbind

Boost has [overloaded operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/bind/bind.html#operators) for boost::bind result type. So `!bind(f, ...)` is equivalent to `bind( logical_not(), bind(f, ...) )`. Some other operators like ||, && can be used as well. Does std::bind have the same features? Can one use `!std::bind(...)`? Is `std::not1` deprecated in c++11?

Comment: No, nothing similar is defined by the standard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So one should still use std::not1 instead of not operator for std::bind? Is there a better way?

Comment: I'd suggest you consider using lambdas. `bind` was basically just a work-around for the lack of lambdas back then.